# Fetch a specific variable value from a text in php

Tags: php

My Text:

```
    //Stores DAta In Text Variable
$text = '{"id":"pay_6ixRYfJxUGVVB5","entity":"payment","amount":1100000,"currency":"INR","status":"authorized","order_id":null,"international":false,"method":"card","amount_refunded":0,"refund_status":null,"captured":false,"description":"Yamaha F310, 6-Strings Acoustic Guitar, Natural","card_id":"card_6ixRZh03lD6ch7","bank":null,"wallet":null,"vpa":null,"email":"a2@gmail.com","contact":"+917863495210","notes":{"address":"446\/3\/1, Lake Miami,
    Calfiornia, USA.
    Pincode: 121212. India."},"fee":null,"service_tax":null,"error_code":null,"error_description":null,"created_at":1479573225}';
```

How can I fetch The value of `amount` in `$amount` variable?

```
echo $amount variable.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a JSON string so use `json_decode` to get a JSON object.

```
$text = '{"id":"pay_6ixRYfJxUGVVB5","entity":"payment","amount":1100000,"currency":"INR","status":"authorized","order_id":null,"international":false,"method":"card","amount_refunded":0,"refund_status":null,"captured":false,"description":"Yamaha F310, 6-Strings Acoustic Guitar, Natural","card_id":"card_6ixRZh03lD6ch7","bank":null,"wallet":null,"vpa":null,"email":"a2@gmail.com","contact":"+917863495210","notes":{"address":"446\/3\/1, Lake Miami,
Calfiornia, USA.
Pincode: 121212. India."},"fee":null,"service_tax":null,"error_code":null,"error_description":null,"created_at":1479573225}';

$obj = json_decode($text);
echo $obj->{'amount'}; // 1100000
echo $obj->{'notes'}->{'address'};
```

Comment: This is working. But when i am using the same process for another value like the address, it is not providing any results. Can you tell me how to fetch the address value?

Comment: Once you create the JSON object all you have to do is reference that JSON key.  See my edit.  For some reason your address key is another JSON object so you have to reference notes first.